# java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to append two different excel stream into the one PDF file using apache poi but when I am going to add the second stream into the pdf then at the time of creating an object of workbook class getting

> java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size exception

```java
PdfPTable table= null;
Document pdfDoc=new Document();

// For Xlsx files           
for(int j=0;j<decodeStreamList.size();j++) {

   //For Xlsx files
   XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(decodeStreamList.get(j));
   XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(wb);
   XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(1);
   ...
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the complete exception so we can figure out where the cause raise? From above question I can only assume that error comes inside the loop.

Comment: My issue is resolved , Now i want append multiple excel sheet into one pdf file.

Comment: Or how to append multiple PdfPTable into one pdf

Comment: Then update your question or 
put the answer for how you have solved and ask a new question for "append multiple excel sheet into one pdf file".